# Variance of Random Matrix

Tags: probability, variance, random-matrix

> Let's consider independent random vectors $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i$, $i = 1, \dots, m$, which are all unbiased for $\boldsymbol\theta$ and that 
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i -
>  \boldsymbol\theta\right)^{T}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i -
>  \boldsymbol\theta\right)\right] = \sigma^2\text{.}$$ Let
>   $\mathbf{1}_{n \times p}$ be the $n \times p$ matrix of all ones.
>
> Consider the problem of finding
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
>  \boldsymbol\theta\right)^{T}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
>  \boldsymbol\theta\right)\right]$$ where $$\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} =
>  \dfrac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i\text{.}$$

My attempt is to notice the fact that $$\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} = \dfrac{1}{m}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_1 & \hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_2 & \cdots & \hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_m
\end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{S}}\mathbf{1}_{m \times 1}$$
and thus
$$\text{Var}(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}) = \dfrac{1}{m^2}\text{Var}(\mathbf{S}\mathbf{1}_{m \times 1})\text{.}$$
**How does one find the variance of a random  matrix times a constant vector?** You may assume that I am familiar with finding variances of linear transformations of a random vector: i.e., if $\mathbf{x}$ is a random vector, $\mathbf{b}$ a vector of constants, and $\mathbf{A}$ a matrix of constants, assuming all are comformable, 
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}] = \mathbf{A}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{x}]+\mathbf{b}$$
$$\mathrm{Var}\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}\right)=\mathbf{A}\mathrm{Var}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{A}^{\prime}$$

Comment: It isn't any different than finding any other variance: the matrix has $m^2$ components and therefore its variance (aka "variance-covariance matrix") is a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^{m^2}$.  It's unclear, though, how your question is related to the situation described at the outset, which concerns finding the variance of the random *vector* (not matrix!) $\hat\theta$.

Comment: @whuber I thought that writing $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}$ as a product of a random matrix $\mathbf{S}$ (above) and a constant vector ($\mathbf{1}_{m \times 1}$) might make this computation cleaner. If this isn't the case, I'll just stick to traditional methods.

Comment: It very well could simplify some aspects of the computation (I haven't checked)--but you have noted the cost: there are a lot more components to keep track of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the matrix computation only (although essentially, this solution is not that different from @DeltaIV's direct calculation), let me first slightly modify your definition of $S$ to its centralized version $\begin{bmatrix}\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta & \cdots & \hat{\theta}_m - \theta\end{bmatrix}$. We can go as follows
\begin{align}
& E[(\hat{\theta} - \theta)^T(\hat{\theta} - \theta)] \\
= & \frac{1}{m^2}E[1^TS^TS1] \\
= & \frac{1}{m^2}1^T E[S^TS] 1 \tag{1} \\
= & \frac{1}{m^2}1^T \begin{bmatrix} E[(\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta)^T(\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta)] & \cdots & E[(\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta)^T(\hat{\theta}_m - \theta)] \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
E[(\hat{\theta}_m - \theta)^T(\hat{\theta}_1 - \theta)] & \cdots & E[(\hat{\theta}_m - \theta)^T(\hat{\theta}_m - \theta)] \end{bmatrix} 1 \\
= & \frac{1}{m^2}1^T\text{diag}(\sigma^2, \ldots, \sigma^2)1 \tag{2} \\
= & \frac{1}{m}\sigma^2.
\end{align}

In $(1)$, we used the fact that for any conformable non-random matrices $A$, $B$ and random matrix $X$, $E[AXB] = AE[X]B$.

In $(2)$, we applied the independence assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Why involving random matrices? This seems much simpler:

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
 \boldsymbol\theta\right)^{T}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
 \boldsymbol\theta\right)\right] =
 \frac{1}{m^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\sum_{j=1}^{m}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_j-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right]=
\frac{1}{m^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right] + \frac{1}{m^2}
  \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j\neq i}^{m} \left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_j-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right]$$

Now,

$$\frac{1}{m^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right] = \frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right]=\frac{m\sigma^2}{m^2}=\frac{\sigma^2}{m}$$

While, for $j\neq i$,

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i-\boldsymbol\theta\right)^T\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_j-\boldsymbol\theta\right)\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}_i^{'T}\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}'_j\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}'_i\right]\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}'_j\right]=0$$

where the penultimate equivalence follows from the independence of   $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}'_i$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}'_j$, and the last equivalence follows from the fact that they are both zero mean.

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
 \boldsymbol\theta\right)^{T}\left(\hat{\boldsymbol\theta} -
 \boldsymbol\theta\right)\right] = \frac{\sigma^2}{m}$$